# Is it acceptable to ask about two or more related games, with similar gameplay elements, in one question and just tag it with those game's tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just started playing Black Mesa, and just recently got Half-Life 2 in Steam (*I know I'm very late to the party*).

I would like to ask a question regarding stealth elements about those two games. (I am thinking the answer will be pretty much the same for both. If not, I guess the difference can be stated.)

My question has been posted here (initially tagged with [black-mesa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-mesa) only): [What stealth elements are in Black Mesa and how does the enemy AI detect the player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85301/what-stealth-elements-are-in-black-mesa-and-how-does-the-enemy-ai-detect-the-pla/85336)

Since both are related (Black Mesa is a modification of the Source game engine, [a game  engine introduced by Half-Life 2](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Half-Life_2#Development), so therefore, they could have similar gameplay features and quirks) and have similar gameplay elements (both are in the same vein as the original [Half-Life](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Half-Life_%28video_game%29)), is it acceptable to ask this in one question and just tag it with both [black-mesa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-mesa) and [half-life-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-2)? Or should I ask the same question for each game, with one game tag per question?

Edit: I eventually just posted another question with the [half-life-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-2) tag here: [What stealth elements are in Half-Life 2 and how does the enemy AI detect the player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85787/what-stealth-elements-are-in-half-life-2-and-how-does-the-enemy-ai-detect-the-pl)

Comment: What, specifically, about the stealth elements are you planning on asking? Why do you think they are similar enough that one question and answer pair will cover both games?

Comment: @MarkTrapp I edited my possible question into my post. About your second question, see my edit in the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: Thanks for expanding: based on your sample questions, definitely [what badp said](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5375/3389).

Comment: The only way I can imagine this being acceptable is if they work identically, and *if you're asking the question you obviously do not know that or you wouldn't be asking*, so ask them separately.

Comment: I see a trend here, games like borderlands 1 and 2 or diablo 2 and 3 are practically the same game in some ways. Many questions about mechanics in one game would generate answers that would work for both games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem about asking a question relevant to two games is that most people will probably only be able to answer that question for one of those two games. Although like you say the answer is likely to be the same for both, unless someone has knowledge of both games they aren't going to be able to completely answer your question(s).

If you ask about each game independently then it means that people who have played one game but not the other are more likely to answer your question(s).

Answer (score 12):

Definitely do ask about different games in different questions. Game engines can be tweaked: HL2, L4D and TF2 bots behave differently, but are on the same engine!

Comment: Now to separate 30+ [dota-2][dota] questions...